# On IIS, batch file variables do not seem to be working.

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am building virtual directories for a setup using the following:

```
echo "Current Drive: %~d1"
set /p var cdr="Enter Install Directory "
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
appcmd add vdir /app.name:"Default Web Site/" /path:/cms /physicalPath:"%cdr%:\websites\cms"
```

If I manually enter the drive letter instead of use cdr everything works fine. The problem I am having is that nothing is displaying. Including %~d1 is empty cdr is empty even after being set.

Im guessing I am just completely missing something here but I dont know what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has two variable names.

```
set /p var cdr="Enter Install Directory "
```

Try this:

```
set /p "cdr=Enter Install Directory "
```

Did you mean this too, btw?  %~d1 uses the first parameter on the command line.

```
echo "Batch file is on Drive: %~d0"
```

This will give you the current drive:

```
echo "The current drive letter is %cd:~0,1%"
```

Comment: That worked! thanks. Can you enlighten me on how to dispaly the current drive letter. Im betting the syntax around %~d1 is wrong.

Comment: Yes I did. Thx again foxidrive.